# Импорт модулей Leaflet Angular (отложенное создание экземпляра класса)

Tags: leafletjs

Как правильно сделать импорт модуля leaflet (например: leaflet-markercluster в Angular) import{ Markercluster } from 'leaflet-markercluster', как быть? На момент импорта модуля Leaflet карта еще не загружена и возникает ошибка (Нужно создавать экземпляр класса по требованию) var cluster= new Markercluster (); Смотрел другие npm пакеты например google-markercluster (https://github.com/novakand/googlemaplib.markercluster/blob/master/index.js) строка 334 (при создании экземпляра класса происходит инициализация) function MarkerClusterer(map, opt_markers, opt_options) { this.extend(MarkerClusterer, google.maps.OverlayView); Может кто-то сталкивался, буду благодарен любой помощи!

Comment: вы уже задали идентичный вопрос

Comment: Это разные карты, поэтому и подход возможен разный!

Comment: решение одинаковое для двух вопросов, я оставил комментарий в первом, но вы на него не отреагировали :)